# How to disabled or hide editoption value to a id session specific with jqgrid?

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to using jqgrid and what I try to do is that a specific id cannot edit the record by placing the status sold

here an example of the condition that I try to apply

```
        if(session_level == 9){
        {name:'status', index:'status', width:150, formatter: editexample, editable:true, stype: 'select', edittype:'select', 
            editoptions: {value: {'':'','New':'New','Cancelled':'Cancelled'} }, search: true,
            searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], value: {'': 'Select', '':'', 'New':'New','Cancelled':'Cancelled'} }
        },
        }else
        {name:'status', index:'status', width:150, formatter: editexample, editable:true, stype: 'select', edittype:'select', 
            editoptions: {value: {'':'','New':'New','Sold':'Sold','Cancelled':'Cancelled'} }, search: true,
            searchoptions:{ sopt:['eq'], value: {'': 'Select', '':'', 'New':'New','Sold':'Sold','Cancelled':'Cancelled'} }
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand correct the question, but you can simple do it like this

```
var my_object = {'': 'Select', '':'', 'New':'New','Cancelled':'Cancelled'};
if(session_level == 9){ 
    my_object['Sold']= 'Sold';
}

jqGrid({
....
    colModel[
    ...
    {name:'status', index:'status', width:150, formatter: editexample, editable:true, stype: 'select', edittype:'select', 
     editoptions: {value: my_object }, search: true, 
     searchoptions : { sopt:['eq'], value: my_object } }
    ...
    ]
});
```

in case this is a JavaScript. In case of PHP or other server side language you should do it in appropriate way